# D3.js zooming and panning - lock on y axis

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to build a stock chart with zooming functionality using D3.js

I'm looking to start with [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434) here and attempt to make the zoom feel more natural for a stock chart. A perfect [example is this](https://www.tradingview.com/e/). So the difference as far as I understand is that zoomng and panning are both locked on the Y-axis, and the only way the Y-axis moves is to autmatically fill the price range of the currently visible data.

Another noticeable difference is that zooming does not zoom into the current position of the mouse like it does in the first example.

How can the example be adjusted to work more closely as the other chart? What is the pertitent code, how should it be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the zoom behaviour to *not* affect the y-axis is simple: just don't attach your y-scale to the zoom behaviour.

In the sample code you linked to, the zoom functionality is added in this line:

```
  this.plot.call(d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .x(this.x)
                    .y(this.y)
                    .on("zoom", this.redraw() )
                    );
```

That creates a zoom behaviour object/function, links it to the graphs x and y scales, and tells it to call the function returned by `this.redraw()` after every zoom event.  The zoom behaviour automatically changes the domain of the scales on zoom, and then the redraw function uses the modified zoom.  If you don't give it a y scale to modify, then zooming won't affect the y domain.

Getting the y scale to automatically adjust to the given extent of the data is a little trickier.  However, remember that the zoom behaviour will have automatically adjusted the domain of the x scale to represent the extent of visible data horizontally.  You'll then have to get the corresponding slice of your data array and figure out the extent of y values from it, set your y domain accordingly, and then call the redraw function (remembering that `this.redraw()` just *returns* the redraw function, to call it within another function you'll need to use `this.redraw()()` ).

To have the zoom be independent of the mouse position, set a [center point](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-center) for the zoom behaviour.